# How to hide a column under a break-point tablet with Bulma?

Tags: css, bulma

Given the following html :

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">Always here</div>
  <div class="column">Hidden on mobile</div>
  <div class="column">Always here</div>
</div>
```

**How to make that the middle column get hidden on mobile ?**

Note: I found no help on this "hide" feature on the [official doc](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/responsiveness/).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`is-hidden-mobile` hides on mobile and `is-hidden-touch` hides on both mobile and tablet. The hide feature is on the official documentation under responsive helpers:

https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/visibility-helpers/#hide

Answer (score 7):

is-hidden-mobile can do the trick

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">Always here</div>
  <div class="column is-hidden-mobile">Hidden on mobile</div>
  <div class="column">Always here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use custom css for that.

```css
.mobile-hidden {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .mobile-hidden {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">Always here</div>
  <div class="column mobile-hidden">Hidden on mobile</div>
  <div class="column">Always here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this css in your file

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.columns .column:nth-child(2) {display: none;}
}
```